# Android: Sorting the table layout content on column basis

Tags: android, sorting, android-tablelayout

i made a table layout with 4 columns and rows were added dynamically.
i want to sort columns in the table layout according to there respective data. first two column contains images and independent to each other and other two columns contain string data.
Can anyone help me on this????

Thanks in advance guys....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a listView for this purpose. Sort your data and update your list with `notifiyDataSetChanged` method.This way it will be easier and more efficient.
Edit: I assume you know how to sort arraylist.

Edit2: If you have to use a table then try to sort data(arraylist), after your sort, loop on your table's rows and update their properties/textViews with your sorted arrayList. You can use getChildAt(int index) method of tableView on your loop.

Comment: thanx for ur reply... i know how to sort arraylist but i want to sort data after putting into the table. so i am looking for some function or class whcih i can use to sort my table as i dont have much time.

Comment: you are saying that i have to create a custom sort this. i know that but i dont have enough time to do that. Thanx again

Comment: Fistly you have to sort your data(you know how to sort with Comparator). That won't be so diffucult after you have sorted arrayList. You only have to loop in table's children and set their new values.

Comment: ok.... i'll give a shot and if i'll get any problem then u'll be the victim of my questions.... lol     Anyways thanx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom Comparator in your adapter. So after you get items you will sort them `Collections.sort(items, new MyComparator());`

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs) {
        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dragon thanx for ur reply... but i am using table layout and replacing the text with images on the run. i can't use the comparator and also i dont have adapter class.